# Angularjs assigning values to scope not working inside function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing a web application in angular js. I have textbox and directive. My textbox should take only values in certain range otherwise error message should be displayed. 
Below HTML code.

```
<input class="" type="text" name="rangeNumber" ng-attr-placeholder="{{ 'DownPayment' }}" ng-model="DownPayment" range-number="range">

<ul class="error-msgs">
    <li ng-show="!form5.rangeNumber.$invalid && form5.rangeNumber.$dirty">Number not in range</li>
</ul>
```

Below is my directive.

```
app.directive('rangeNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            if (!ctrl) return;

            var range = scope.$eval(attrs.rangeNumber);
            range = range.split(',').map(Number);

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                value = +value;
                var isValidRange = !(value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]);

                ctrl.$setValidity('range', isValidRange);
                return value;
            });


        }
    };
});
```

Below is my function where i am assigning range.

```
function fillsiebelloandetails(SiebelLoanDetails)
{
  //some http ajax call and get values and assign it ti range.
  $scope.range = '1,7';
}
```

Here I am facing problem if I assign   $scope.range = '1,7'; inside fillsiebelloandetails it is not working. if I write    $scope.range = '1,7'; outside function it works fine. May I know why this is happening? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: i guess you may try ng-minlength or ng-maxlength..

Comment: Is your fillsiebelloandetails(SiebelLoanDetails) being called when page loads?

Comment: Yes. On page load fillsiebelloandetails(SiebelLoanDetails) i am calling.

Comment: Hi Vivz. May i know why this is not working on page load?

Comment: Post more code, from the above code it is unclear as to what is causing the issue.

Comment: inside fillsiebelloandetails i am making some ajax and two values i will get assign it to range. For example minvalue is 10 and maxvalue is 20 so  $scope.range = 'minvalue,maxvalue';

Comment: Can you show the code for this and the above will work if you put it outside the function?

Comment: you can always add debugger. check whether it is being called on page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need watch rangeNumber changes in directive

```
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
        if (!ctrl) return;

        scope.$watch(attrs.rangeNumber, function(){
            var range = scope.$eval(attrs.rangeNumber);
            range = range.split(',').map(Number);

            ctrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
               value = +value;
               var isValidRange = !(value >= range[0] && value <= range[1]);

               ctrl.$setValidity('range', isValidRange);
              return value;
            });

        })



    }
```

Comment: For example if var a=10 and var b=20 then how can i write  $scope.range=?

Comment: $scope.range = a + ',' + b

Answer (score 0):

When you define a variable within function its scope is treated as functional(local) scope so the issue has occurred.You should declare the variable at the directive level scope.For this, you can try as follows.

1. Declare the variable outside the function.
2. Then assign the value from inside the function.

Eg.

```
......

    var vm=this;
    vm.range=[];   //declare variable outside the function 
    function fillsiebelloandetails(SiebelLoanDetails)
    {
      //some http ajax call and get values and assign it ti range.
      vm.range = '1,7';
    }
```

I think i might be helpful for you.